# If condition based on Activeprofile

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to run a query in `H2` in-memory for testing purposes. Due to `H2` limitation, certain syntax does not work. I am looking to change the syntax based on `@Activeprofile` in `Spring Boot`. My code would look something like this:

```
if (@Activeprofile("Test")) {
    query = "something for test"
} else {
    query = "something for prod/stage" 
}
```

Is this possible? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to inject an `Environment` Bean into your code.

Like this:

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;
```

You can then use the `.getActiveProfiles()` method.

```
if (Arrays.asList(environment.getActiveProfiles()).contains("...") {
    ...
}
```

More on this can be found [here.](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles)

Comment: thats exactly what i wanted. Thank you so much.